# How to correctly test method containing FluentValidator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluentvalidation

I have simple service

```
    public bool Validate(Model model, string site, bool sholdUseSpecialRules)
    {
        // logging

        var result = modelValidator.Validate(model, options =>
        {
            options.IncludeRuleSets(site).IncludeRulesNotInRuleSet();
            if (sholdUseSpecialRules) options.IncludeRuleSets("UseSpecialRules");
        });

        // result message handling

        return result.IsValid;
    }

    // modelValidator is of type FluentValidation.IValidator<Model>()
```

how to unit test if proper rule have been applied?

In documentation they say to use real object. But this should be unit test so no dependencies. Validator itself is being tested somewhere else so I do not want to test it here second time.

Comment: _" so no dependencies and validator itself is being tested somewhere else so I do not care about it here"_ please clarify. And if you don't test real objects, your unit test is not representative, thus not really valuable...

Comment: There should be a period after word dependencies.  And word "and" should be removed.